# How to use value count occurrences and multiplying them by a integer to produce a value?

Tags: python, pandas

I work for a transport company and I do billing. I want to be able to automate my excel sheets so that I import an excel sheet and it does the billing for me.

- I know how to import a excel sheet.
- I know how to use the .value_counts() function to count the number of occurrences for billed service.
- I don't know how to take the values and multiply them to produce the service fee.

I have created a mock data frame of what my excel sheet produces. I just don't know how to take those values that produce by value counts and automatically calculate a service fee for me.

```
d = ['wheelchair', 'ambulatory', 'wheelchair', 'ambulatory','wheelchair', 'ambulatory', 'wheelchair', 'ambulatory']
df = DataFrame(data = d, columns = ['Device'])
  Device
0  wheelchair
1  ambulatory
2  wheelchair
3  ambulatory
4  wheelchair
5  ambulatory
6  wheelchair
7  ambulatory

typeoftransport = df['Device'].value_counts()
typeoftransport
ambulatory    4
wheelchair    4
```

I want it to produce this

```
ambulatory, has 4 rides, charge with fee 8.00$, total fee for service $32.00
wheelchair, has 4 rides, charge with fee 20.00$, total fee for service $80.00
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack! The following can help you...

```
from collections import Counter

d = ['wheelchair', 'ambulatory', 'wheelchair', 'ambulatory','wheelchair', 'ambulatory', 'wheelchair', 'ambulatory']

price = {'wheelchair' : 8, 'ambulatory' : 20} ##you've to assign price of every item in your database

c = Counter(d)

for key, value in c.items():
    print(f"{key}, has {value} rides, charge with a fee of {price[key]}$, total fee for service {price[key]*value}$")
```

Hope it helps. Peace out!

Answer (score 0):

```
mapping = {"ambulatory":8,"wheelchair":10}
v_c = df['Device'].value_counts()
for i, j in zip(v_c.index, v_c.values):
    print("{}, has {} rides, charge with fee {}, total fee is {}".format(i, j, mapping[i],mapping[i] * j))
```